# How to make the app workflow easily understood?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, hints

I am working on an app that should work like this:

1. user searches his favourite items
2. he clicks "Like" on his favourite items
3. he presses "Suggest items" to discover some new ones

I am struggling to show the user the process of doing that. Here is a mockup:

[image: image of basic ux mockup]

I was thinking on showing some hints when the item box is empty (before search). However, I can't do that because I plan on having some initial data (items that he may like, so he doesn't have to search them).

I am looking for a way to either show hints, or a way to simplify this process.

Comment: What is the porpoise of the user clicking like? with suggest do you mean "suggestED"?

Comment: @rewobs User clicks "Like" on his favourite items. Then he clicks "Suggest items" to find similar ones.

Comment: "Suggest items" means that you want **the user** to make a suggestion, if you want the users to see the suggestions that you calculate it should be "Suggested items". Also "like" doesn't give the user a clear idea of the usefulness of clicking it.

Comment: @rewobs No, "Suggest items" means that based on the likes of the user, we can suggest them new items.

Comment: What I mean is that **in english** what you want to express is **Suggested**, that is an adjetive for items =  the items that are suggested. Suggest is a verb, so if you write "Suggest items" you are requesting the user to make a suggestion, not to receive one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not automatically suggest items as the user makes selections. I would locate the "Suggested Items" below the item selections similar to how Netflix suggests alternative titles once a user has viewed a title. Getting a good default will be important so use what you know about the user  (behavior, preferences, profile) to drive the initial presentation. I would recommend once a user has made a selection the suggestion recalculation happen asynchronously. If the goal is to use the recommendations to drive more "Likes" then make the suggestions actionable. Also, if the intent is to build some sort of profile consider reducing cognitive load by listing the users selections somewhere for reference, as "Liked" items may be removed from view if the user performs a search or selected suggestions are recalculated.

Comment: Important to note this is a good answer because it *DOES NOT try teach user how to user your app* (as the question implies) but rather makes app behave more seamlessly for the user.

Comment: I am glad you properly understood my app. I am having the same opinion as you, and I find the current approach weird - that's why I posted this.

Comment: I will go with some kind of asynchronous approach